# Why my app crashes with fatal error, but only on first launch?

Tags: ios, swift

When I launch my app, and click the button, the app crashes with `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, but when I start the simulator again, everything is fine when I click it.

This is the code the button executes:

```
func showProfile(sender:AnyObject?){
    let profile = App.mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profile") as! Profile

    //Here is the error
    animateToView(self.navigationController!, view: profile, midX: self.profileItem.frame.midX, midY: self.profileItem.frame.midY)
}
```

Comment: try to put it with static values and see...

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the crashing line and check your variables for non-nil values, especially `self.navigationController` since that's the one you're explicitly unwrapping.

Comment: Yes the `navigationController` is the problem, but I don´t know why it is only at the first time I launch the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `navigationController`

```
if let _ = self.navigationController {
    animateToView(self.navigationController!, view: profile, midX: self.profileItem.frame.midX, midY: self.profileItem.frame.midY)
}
```

Comment: Oke thanks, yes it is the `navigationController`, but why it is only at the first time?

Comment: Please show some more code of your that will help to understand why this is happening.

Comment: What would you like to see from the code? I added the `UINavigationController` in the storyboard(embed in a `UIViewController`) :)

Comment: I have a custom subclass of `UIButton`, and I add a target to this button:
`self.profileItem.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Main.showProfile(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`
and I add the button in the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: Are you having multiple storyboard in your project?

Comment: Yes I have, and I the variables with the storyboards are in another class("App")

Comment: I think that was the issue check properly that viewcontroller is properly embed with navigationcontroller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120166/discussion-between-julian-pomper-and-ndoc).